# Using D-Link 2750U WIFI Router for WIFI

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I am having trouble configuring the D-Link 2750U WIFI Router. I have a broadband connection with a static IP ( 192.168.1.xxx) through Ethernet cable. Now, I would like use this broadband connection to connect to  the router and connect 2 computers, 1 Laptop and an Android Phone.

The internet connection I donot connect to the DSL input. Is it possible to configure the 2750U WIFI Router, where I connect the Ethernet cable to one of the 4 ports and share the internet through LAN as well as WiFi ?

Or, do you think that the D-Link 2750U is completely useless for the kind of setup I have ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I really understand what you're asking. so I'll go over a few possibilities.

First, you need to recognize that the D-Link 2750U is designed to be your primary "gateway" device. That means it's only meant to connect to the Internet via its DSL port and doesn't have a typical Ethernet-based WAN port available. If it is not being directly connected to a DSL line, it is only useful as a Wi-Fi AP and switch - Ethernet-to-Ethernet routing is not possible with this device.

On to the scenarios:

**1. Your ISP provides you with a "dummy" DSL modem.** (No routing/switching/WiFi functionality built in. Only communication ports available are 1 DSL and one LAN Ethernet.)

The D-Link 2750U cannot be connected to this device and serve any useful purpose. "Dummy" modems are designed to only connect to one device on the LAN, so you will need an Ethernet-to-Ethernet router (which the D-Link 2750U is not) if you want to share the connection around while using the ISP's modem as the gateway device. To use the D-Link 2750U here, you'll need to contact your ISP to obtain the necessary information and credentials for configuring it as your primary gateway. Then, you'd remove the ISP's modem from your network and put the D-Link 2750U in its place. This is the way it was meant to be used.

**2. Your ISP provides you with a "home gateway" device.** (This is a modem with routing & switching functionality built-in, and may also have Wi-Fi or other features added. These will usually have multiple LAN Ethernet ports.)

You *can* use the D-Link 2750U in this network, but it would be in a relatively limited capacity. Since you already have a device acting as a DHCP server and performing other routing functionality for your network, you would need to disable these functions on the D-Link 2750U before connecting it to the home gateway. Then, you'll connect a cable from one of the LAN ports on the ISP's gateway to a LAN port on the D-Link 2750U. From there, the D-Link 2750U would just be acting as a network switch and Wireless AP.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, because the four LAN ports and the wireless port are connected on Layer 2, and this group is in turn connected to the WAN port on Layer 3. The wireless router works in one of these two set-ups:

1. **With an internet connection**: In this case, the router will have a WAN network (your internet connection) and a LAN network. On the LAN side, it will use DHCP to assign private I.P's to the clients, acting as their default gateway and DHCP server at the same time. It will then use NAT to make the two networks (LAN and WAN) pass traffic to each other using address translation (from private to public and vice versa). For this set-up, you could make use of the internet connection you have, plug it into the WAN port, and configure the wireless router to connect to the WAN network using the method that your ISP specified (in this case, broadband).
2. **Without an internet connection**: In this case, all the devices will be connected either wirelessly and/or to the four LAN ports. You will have no internet connection, just a private network. The wan port could not be used in this set-up.

There's, however, a special case in which the set-up you mentioned could work: If the ISP is supplying you with a DHCP and NAT service, in addition to a public I.P. This is very rare, I have seen it done only once. In this case, the ISP will provide the DHCP and NAT for you, and you could just use the main internet connection to any LAN port and then connect other devices. It should work because the router will simply connect your premises to the ISP via Layer 2, while the ISP will do the Layer 3 work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible I flashed Russion firmware and I am able to get WAN finction in my Dlink 2750U. Now I can use ethernet as input and Wi-fi as output.

Comment: Can you give the link to download that firmware?